# Forward delegation in Object Composition :How does traits and Mixing solves this?

Tags: oop

One drawback to using composition in place of inheritance is that all of the methods being provided by the composed classes must be implemented in the derived class, even if they are only forwarding methods.
Looking for the solution to this problem I came cross something called as Traits and mixin ( available in language like scala,Perl 6) . However I haven't been compleltly able to understand the idea behind traits and mixins.

My question is how does traits (or Mixins) solve the problem of delegation with composition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Perl or Scala programmer, but no one else has tried to answer your question, so I will attempt it. Traits or mixins are an alternative to multiple inheritance. C++ implemented multiple inheritance, but there were some problems with it. Successive languages like Java and C# decided to implement only single inheritance. But single inheritance can be inconvenient, just as you say; if you want to use methods from multiple classes, you must compose instances of those classes and then write methods to forward messages to the composed objects.

Traits/mixins are a solution to inconvenience of single inheritance. Instead of composing objects and writing forwarding methods yourself, the programming language does the work for you. If your object does not understand some message sent to it, the runtime environment will look through all of the traits/mixin to see if one of them understands the message. If a trait/mixin understands the message, then that trait's implementation of the is executed. This lets you bundle commonly used functionality into a single component, called a trait or mixin, so you use it in many places.

I think the important advantage of traits/mixins over multiple inheritance is that when different mixins implement methods with the same name, you can predict which method will be executed. Knowing which method would be executed in C++ was a problem. See the Wikipedia article on the "diamond problem" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)